# SQL mixed number and character type

Tags: sql

I have a number of tables in an sqlite3 database which have a `cost INT` attribute.

I now am in a situation where in one of my tables there are three possible valid values for cost: `NULL`, a number, or 'X'.

Is there a way to allow entering both numbers and characters into an attribute.

I had considered making cost a `CHAR(1)` and:

```
CONSTRAINT ck_cost CHECK (ISNUMERIC(cost) OR cost = 'X')
```

But then I would not be able to set cost values to literal integers, they would have to be placed in quotes (`'1'` instead of `1`). This would be inconsistent with my other tables.

Comment: What is the reasoning for a cost being X?

Comment: Just add another field ("attribute"), indicating that cost is X. Saving numbers as text is only a little better than saving dates as text - both approaches fail sooner or later.

Comment: @podiluska 'X' means dynamic cost

Comment: @Arvo thats pretty good - answer that and i'll accept

Comment: what would NULL represent, something different than 0?

Comment: @msmucker0527 NULL means that the cost has not been entered (and might not be 0)- there is no logical default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Promoted my comment to answer as requested :)*

Just add another field ("attribute"), indicating that cost is X. Saving numbers as text is only a little better than saving dates as text - both approaches fail sooner or later.